# passing composed commands as arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Consider a script `pass_command`

```
ls | "$@"
```

It accepts named commands as arguments

```
pass_command sort
#prints files sorted
```

Which is good enough for all practical purposes. I'm curious though, Is there a mechanism that lets me pass compound commands? Something like

```
pass_command (sort | uniq) #Forgive the silly example.
```

Edit:
A more complicated example that motivated this question.

```
until who | grep mary
do
  sleep 60
until
```

Signals mary logging on. I wanted to generalize this to signal some event. The intuitive idea was this:

```
#watchfor
until "$@"
do
  sleep 60
done
```

And then you would call it as

```
watchfor (who | grep mary)
```

That was the idea. You can give the argument a name, and the above works fine. It just made me think of this.

I suppose I was trying to understand the most idiomatic way of hiding the signaling command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use `eval` in the script as soon as `$@` is more than a simple command (the argument to the script has to be passed as a quoted string):

```
ls | eval "$@"
```

But then again, this would also be the same as

```
pass_command sort | uniq
```

i.e., you pass the `sort` command and the use `uniq` on the output.

I see no real use for this sort of script or function as Unix's pipelining capability seems to cover most practical applications.